# cursor execute live data in python using mySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have a question about how cursors execute queries in python. Here is the block of code in question:

```
for sleeper in range (2):
    cur.execute("QUERY")
    for row in cur:
        Demand.append(str(row[2]))
        ComponentID.append(str(row[3]))
        DeviceID.append(str(row[1]))
        read_time.append(str(row[4]))
print read_time
del read_time[:]
```

So all of the lists that I am appending contain live data that changes by the second. Ive noticed that when I print read_time at the end of my code the list is the exact same each time. My question is, once a query is executed is the data always the same? I would like to see a read time such as this:

```
2018-08-20 15:39:08 
2018-08-20 15:59:25
```

and instead i am seeing:

```
2018-08-20 15:39:08
2018-08-20 15:39:08
```

Comment: What is your query? It’s clearly not the string `"QUERY"`. Presumably it’s something that `SELECT`s four values. And if that fourth value is something like `NOW()` then it’s entirely up to the database whether to run that once per row, once per result set, or once per entire query, but almost all databases will do one of the last two. In which case the code you’ve shown us, and Python in general, is completely irrelevant, and you should be asking a SQL question about your SQL query.

Comment: The query is `SELECT e_id, device_id, inst_demand,component_id, read_time FROM device_demand.`